# Redefine ios method

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi I need the redefine an ios method (CLLocationCoordinate2DMake) with this code:

```
static inline CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocationCoordinate2DInlineMake(CLLocationDegrees latitude, CLLocationDegrees longitude)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = latitude;
    coord.longitude = longitude;
    return coord;
}

#define CLLocationCoordinate2DMake CLLocationCoordinate2DInlineMake
```

But I don't know where put this code...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I assume you're working from:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/09/backwards-compatibility-if-apple-starts-polishing/

Either way, you just need to stick it in a header which you'll import wherever you intend to use `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`. You could even include it in you .pch file if you really wanted to, which would make it available everywhere with no further effort on your part.